# Does islam allow a women to marry whom she wants to?

Tags: nikah, women

Some families don't allow women to marry whom they like.they even don't ask her when they choose someone as her life partner. Parents do not go for it and don't take their opinion.may be she like someone else.

Is it right or not please tell me?
Does Islam allow her to tell her opinion about that matter?

Comment: Both men and women have few restrictions place on them in Islam w.r.t marriage esp when it comes to marrying a non-muslim. But in general, a muslimah can marry another Muslim man provided that he is not of a bad character.  Infact, in Islam a lady can't be married off to anyone without her consent! Hence, her opinion definitely matters.

Answer (score 1):

Islam allow her to tell her opinion about her own marriage, her permission should be sought for it. It is not right to completely ignore her opinion and feelings.

> A woman without a husband has more right to her person than her
>   guardian, and a virgin's consent must be asked from her, and her
>   silence implies her consent.
>
> (https://sunnah.com/muslim/16/78)
>
> Narrated `Aisha: I asked the Prophet, "O Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)! Should
>   the women be asked for their consent to their marriage?" He said,
>   "Yes." I said, "A virgin, if asked, feels shy and keeps quiet." He
>   said, "Her silence means her consent."
>
> (https://sunnah.com/bukhari/89/7)
>
> Narrated Khansa bint Khidam Al-Ansariya: that her father gave her in
>   marriage when she was a matron and she disliked that marriage. So she
>   went to Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) and he declared that marriage invalid.
>
> (https://sunnah.com/bukhari/67/74)

However you also must understand that when woman is young and inexperienced, then she is easily drawn to or entrapped by unsuitable prospectors and her parents can make more informed decision on her behalf. At the end of the day they are on her side and only want to chose what is best for her.